# Gameing iframe responsive

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to make my iframe responsive.

Following is my code

```css
.game_frame iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="game_frame">
    <iframe src="http://www.freeonlinegames.com/embed/142842" width="800" height="400" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even i changed this

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

Too

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-md-12 text-center">
```

but still facing problem and my iframe is not in center. I don't wanna use full width iframe, i wanna

> width="800" height="400"

EDIT :- [Iframe on Dextop site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUEdu.png) , [Iframe on Mobile site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sZ2s.png)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by responsive?

Comment: on dextop gaming iframe is perfect [snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/HYf6XRk.png) but on mobile gamign iframe is not showing 100%. only half is showing [snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/377xD9A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't have a 2:1 ratio (for your 800x400 example) responsive embed utility; you'd have to add a class to your CSS and HTML:

```
.embed-responsive-2by1::before { 
    padding-top: 50%;
}
```

*Edit:*

I wasn't able to properly load `http://www.freeonlinegames.com/embed/142842` in any browser I tried for whatever reason, but the the following code *should* work; just replace the dummy `img` with the `iframe`: https://codepen.io/pixleight/pen/KvEWRJ/

```css
.embed-responsive-2by1::before {
  padding-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-2by1">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/800x400" class="embed-responsive-item" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing the defined width and height on the iframe. I'll take a look more closely soon when I'm at a computer and not on my phone.

Comment: @samparker025 I don't know what browser you're using, but I wasn't able to properly load `http://www.freeonlinegames.com/embed/142842` in any browser I tried. I expanded my answer above using a dummy image in place of the iframe as an example.